# Convertir un formato de fecha en Java

Tags: java, xml, date

Tengo un método para hacer parse desde un xml en forma de string, a un objeto Petición.
Pero en el xml la fecha me viene tal que así:

2009-06-12T00:00:00+02:00

Entonces no sé que formato darle al SimpleDateFormat para poder convertir eso a Date. Que iría dentro del paréntesis en:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("");
```

Cuando ejecuto el método me da el siguiente error:

```
Unparseable date: "2009-06-12T00:00:00+02:00"
```

Escribo el método aquí abajo:

```
public Date convertirFecha(String s) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date fecha = formatter.parse(s);

        return fecha;
    }
```

Comment: Por mi parte he hecho una pequeña prueba, y poniendo esta máscara obtengo un `Date` sin problemas `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. También veo que tenemos un constructor de `SimpleDateFormat` que además recibe otro parámetro de tipo `Locale` que te podría venir bien.

Comment: @DiegoLoL cuando intento obtener el Date me da el siguiente error: Unparseable date: "2009-06-12T00:00:00+02:00"

Comment: Tienes que darte que tienes barras inclinadas en lugar de guiones medios. Cambia `"yyyy/MM/dd"` por `"yyyy-MM-dd"` dentro de tu método.

Comment: @DiegoLoL me di cuenta al poco de pegar el método, fue un fallo muy tonto. Muchas gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende del formato que quieras darle a la fecha, si quieres mostrar solo día mes año, o como mostrarlo

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Aquí tienes los tipos de formato que puedes poner y eso es lo que tienes que poner entre las comillas

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
```

Resultado 12:08 PM

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
```

Resultado Wed, Jul 4, '01

Comment: El problema es que sale el siguiente error: Unparseable date: "2009-06-12T00:00:00+02:00" , he editado la pregunta para que se entienda mejor la situación.

Comment: Tienes barras inclinadas en lugar de guiones medios. Cambia "yyyy/MM/dd" por "yyyy-MM-dd" dentro de tu método

Comment: me di cuenta al poco de pegar el método,fue un error tonto. Gracias igualmente!